# Where is Short.toString(short s, int radix)?

Tags: java

`Short.parseShort(String s, int radix)` exists, as does `Integer.parseInt(String s, int radix)` and `Long.parseLong(String s, int radix)`.

`Integer.toString(int i, int radix)` and `Long.toString(long l, int radix)` exist.

`Short.toString(short s)`, `Integer.toString(int i)` and `Long.toString(long l)` all exist.

So why is there no `Short.toString(short s, int radix)`?

(It can't be because you can always cast your short to an int and use the `Integer` class' method, the same argument could be made for getting rid that; you could always cast your int to a long and use the `Long` class' version.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the implementation of `Short.toString(short s)`:

```
public static String toString(short s) {
    return Integer.toString((int)s, 10);
}
```

So, just use `Integer`. (Note that the implementation is different for `Integer` and `Long`)

Comment: the only difference in implementation is the bigger size of the char[] buf, right?  So why not an implementation in the Short class which uses an even smaller buf?

Comment: Same goes for `Byte` btw - it uses `Integer`. I'd assume it's an unnecessary optimization.

Comment: @Tom: because it isn't worth it. Generally you should prefer `int` over `short`/`byte`. Prefer `double` over `float`.

Answer (score 1):

The arguement *is* that you can use the Integer.toString(int, int)!

Looking at the code for Short.toString(short) (Java 6), it uses the Integer version under the covers:

```
public static String toString(short s) {
     return Integer.toString((int)s, 10);
}
```